# Preposterous Datagram length

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans, datagram

While testing my program, I got incredibly strange errors. The program is written in C++ and uses SDL, and SDL_TTF. I'm programming in Netbeans on a Mac OSX 10.7.5. I was running the program from the Netbeans console, so all prints and couts are shown within netbeans. While running the program, I looked at the console and there were three odd errors. My program hadn't crashed, and as far as I could tell nothing was wrong.

> Nov 24 17:00:35 130-127-40-247.lever.resnet.clemson.edu eden[72168] : kCGErrorRangeCheck: >CGSDispatchDatagramsFromStream : Preposterous datagram length -805306368
>
> Nov 24 17:00:35 130-127-40-247.lever.resnet.clemson.edu eden[72168] : kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
> Nov 24 17:00:35 130-127-40-247.lever.resnet.clemson.edu eden[72168] : CGSResetPortStream:
> Resetting corrupt stream on connection 0x1e01f.

//The program kept running, and I ended it normally

> RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 2m 40s; user: 2s; system: 2m 35s

The "130-127-40-247.lever.resnet.clemson.edu" is the internet network I was connected to, and eden is the name of the executable of my program. I looked up the error and a few people said it was from dropbox doing hackish things. I have dropbox installed but It wasn't running at the time. Google Drive was, however. Does anyone know how these error got into my program's display and if I should be worried?